# Is "object is not None" the same as if object?

Tags: python

I typically use "is not None" to test whether an Object is empty or not. I am seeing code just use 'if object'. Are they the same thing?

for example,

```
if Dog:
  ...
```

VS

```
if Dog is not None:
  ...
```

Comment: `if Dog is not None` works if Dog is `False`, but the first doesn’t.  The first checks the truthiness and the second checks for things that aren’t `None` exclusively.

Comment: What about if Dog can only be None or not None? In that case, I can simply use 'if Dog' test?

Comment: `import this` -> "Explicit is better than implicit."

Comment: Doing `if object:` returns true if `object` is *falsey* - any value that resolves to false, including but not limited to `0`, `[]`, `""`, `{}`, `False`, and `None`. The comparison `if object is None` is more limited, because it only checks for one of those values.

Comment: `[] is not None`, `{} is not None`, `'' is not None`. I think you should reconsider how you "typically" test for emptiness. Typical use is not to test for `None`-ness, but to test whether the object is truthy. Empty lists, dicts, zero-length strings, etc. are all falsey.

Answer (score 6):

The syntax `if Dog` calls the `__bool__` (or `__len__`) magic method of class `Dog` to get its boolean representation.

Some modules implement their object's `__bool__` method such that it will raise an exception if called such as pandas:

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous...
```

Though by default objects will return `True` if neither of those magic methods are implemented. Most builtins implement the `__bool__` or `__len__` magic method so using them in an `if` statement is normal.

So for a `list` you can just do:

```
my_list = []
if my_list:
    print("List has objects in it") # This will not be called with this code.
```

Classes will, by default, return `True`:

```
class Foo():
    # Classes do this by default
    # def __bool__(self):
    #     return True
    pass
f = Foo()
if f:
     print("This variable references an object") # This will be called
```

You can implement your class in such a way that python can better understand what is considered Truthy and what is considered Falsey:

```
class Foo():
    def __init__(self):
        self.my_list = []
    def append(self, ele):
        self.my_list.append(ele)
    # I could implement this instead of `len`
    # def __bool__(self):
    #     # Some object will raise an exception here
    #     return bool(self.my_list)
    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.my_list) > 1

f = Foo()
print("True") if f else print("False") # False
f.append(2)
print("True") if f else print("False") # False
f.append(2)
print("True") if f else print("False") # True
```

To read more see [truth value testing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing)

Comment: By default, classes do too. If not explicitly implemented, `if classInstance` effectively resolves to `if classInstance is not None`

Comment: An exception won’t be raised. All custom-written objects have a default `__bool__` of `True`.

Comment: @NChauhan "May", I will reword it, but some classes (such as NumPy) will raise an exception if the truth of an object is ambiguous.

Comment: `if Dog attempts to cast Dog to a boolean object.` ? There is no casting, it tries to create a boolean object using class `bool` with argument `Dog`

Comment: There's no casting *or* Boolean creation, just [truth value testing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing).